# NetLogo: kill rest of agentset

Tags: netlogo, kill, agentset

```
to change-vgags
  ifelse (((-0.007333 * x * x) + (0.07333 * x) + 1) = 1)
  [stop]
  [ifelse (((-0.007333 * x * x) + (0.07333 * x) + 1) > 1) 
  [ask n-of (((((-0.007333 * x * x) + (0.07333 * x) + (1)) / 48) - (1 / 48)) * 590) gags with [pcolor = red - 2] [ hatch 1 ]]
  [ask n-of (((1 / 48) - (((-0.007333 * x * x) + (0.07333 * x) + 1) / 48)) * 590) gags with [pcolor = red - 2] [die]]]
```

The top code is an existing functioning code that I have. Since the gags decrease, they will follow the last equation that tells them to die. However, I get to a point where it wants 15 gags to die, but I only have 10 left in the agentset. So I tried to add a new line of code directly after, but it is still giving me the same problem, so obviously, it isn't right. The line of code that I wrote is written below.

```
  if (((1 / 48) - (((-0.007333 * x * x) + (0.07333 * x) + 1) / 48)) * 590) > count gags with [pcolor = red - 2] [ask gags with [pcolor = red - 2] [die]]
end
```

If anyone has any advice on how to fix this problem, I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
ask n-of ... gags with [pcolor = red - 2] [ die ]
```

with:

```
let quota ...
let targets gags with [pcolor = red - 2]
ask n-of min (list quota count targets) targets [ die ]
```

or if that seems a bit hard to read, you could always:

```
let quota ...
let targets gags with [pcolor = red - 2]
if quota > count targets
  [ set quota count targets ]
ask n-of quota targets [ die ]
```